# Background image disappears in Chrome while sliding the page

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, background-image

I am using curtain effect for my pages. Most of my pages has a fixed background image and the text(div) will slide over the background image. I am using below piece of code for the background. It works fine in Firefox and IE but in Chrome the background images disappear once I slide down and up.

```
  html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If I remove "fixed" from the above code block, the background images does appear. But I am losing the effect  i.e: The background image is also moving with the text.
I need the similar effect as in this link: [FullPageBackgroundImage](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php)

The above link has a single page and it works fine but in my case I have 5 pages with the curtain effect.(See this example: [Curtain Effect](http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/eticket/story?page=Dock-Ellis)

Can someone suggest what are the other possibilities to have this working in Chrome with the background images fixed and sliding text.

Comment: Please could you add all the relevant source code and a demo of this problem to the question? It is difficult to answer without the code.